# Why is it so hard to find a generating function for Somos' sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The sequence is $\{1,2,12,576,1658880,\dots\}$. The $n$th number is obtained by squaring the $(n-1)$-th number and multiplying by $n$. So we start with  $a_1=1$, $a_2=1^22=2$, $a_3=(1^22)^23=12$.  In other words, $a_n=a_{n-1}^2n$. This doesn't seem like a terribly complicated sequence yet I can't find anywhere a closed generating function. I assume it is because so far there is none. But what makes this sequence so difficult?

Comment: The generating function will never converge except at $x=0$.

Comment: "But what makes this sequence so difficult?" The square in the transform $a_{n-1}\to a_n=n(a_{n-1})^2$.

Comment: The comment about convergence is true because the sequence grows quickly, but it is not sufficient. A good example is the generating function for factorials which also grows quickly. It was studied by Euler and has continued fraction expressions also. Still, it would be strange to find some expression for the generating function of this sequence. See http://oeis.org/A052129.